# Offset horizontal border start

Tags: html, css

Please refer to the following [mock-up here](http://jsfiddle.net/boggey79/co5cjb6f/). I am trying to get the horizontal borders to start at the right hand edge of the left borders (i.e. no intersect).

Much like this:

[image: Borders with no intersect]

**CSS**

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
li:first-of-type{
   border-top: solid 1pt #cccccc;
}

li{
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1pt #cccccc;
    border-left: solid 6px #cc0000;
}
```

**MARKUP**

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I omitted to mention that eventually those left edges on the `<li></li>`s will be different colours so unfortunately applying the border the `<ul>` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add the top and bottom borders using pseudo elements like this:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    padding:10px;
    border-left: solid 6px #cc0000;
    position: relative;
}

li:first-of-type:before {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    content: "";
    display:block;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li:after {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display:block;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/javotLrb/

Comment: This is the best answer after taking some time to try a few of the suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you update your CSS to this:

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
  border-left: solid 6px #cc0000;
}
li:first-of-type{
  border-top: solid 1pt #cccccc;
}

li{
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1pt #cccccc;
}
```

You will achieve what you want.

The problem was that borders will bisect each other at the half way point on the same html element so that miters look correct.  Adding the left border to the parent element solved the problem.

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1sogmsqe/1/

*OR*

You can add an inline element to the css which would allow you to change the color of the left border:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="static"><span class='line first'>Menu Item</span></li>
    <li class="static"><span class='line'>Menu Item</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span class='line'>Menu Item</span></li>
    <li class="static"><span class='line'>Menu Item</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:0;
}
li .first {
  border-top: solid 1pt #cccccc;
}

li.active {
  border-left: solid 6px #00cc00;
}

li.static {
  border-left: solid 6px #cc0000;
}

li .line {
  border-bottom: solid 1pt #cccccc;
  padding:10px;
  display:block;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1sogmsqe/3/

Comment: Thanks, although I should have mentioned the menu items `<li></li>` will eventually have different coloured edges.

Comment: Ah, in that case you could add another class inline on the <li>.

Comment: I added another fiddle and explanation that explains how to do that.

Comment: +1 Thanks, the inner span prevents the border intersect. I also posted another solution I came across that uses the pseudo element `:before`.

Comment: I guess this is all right if you're ok with the extra markup. But you don't need any extra classes or markup to achieve this. So unless you've got a good reason not to, I'd go for pseudo elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the list in a div, setting border-left to the color, and remove the padding from the ul.

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border-left: solid 6px #cc0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
  border-left: solid 6px #cc0000;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li:first-of-type{
   border-top: solid 1pt #cccccc;
}

li{
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: solid 1pt #cccccc;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I kind of solved this using the psuedo element `:before`. I say "kind of" as it's not removing the intersect as per my original post but stretching it to the left edge of the left border.

http://jsfiddle.net/boggey79/n0eppvmc/

It did require me to assign a class to the `<li>`. In the example I've used `.active` edged green and `.recessive` edged grey, but I suppose you can just add more for different colours.

**CSS**

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}

li:first-of-type{
   border-top: solid 1pt #cccccc;
}

li {
     position:relative;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
}

.active:before{
    content: "";
    background-color: #3ab54a;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.recessive:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #cccccc;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

**MARKUP**

```
<ul>
    <li class='active'>Menu Item</li>
    <li class='recessive'>Menu Item</li>
    <li class='recessive'>Menu Item</li>
    <li class='recessive'>Menu Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could also go the other way around and add the top and bottom borders using pseudo elements (look at my answer if you're interested).